# Feast of contest questions probably in number theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, algebraic-number-theory

So I'm from a math contest that nearly finished me completely. There were things I had never seen till today and some(regrettably) confused me. I just want to improve and learn from this thing. Here are the questions I had zero clue about. Please help me out with at least one so I can improve. Besides, I think they all just have a trick to them.

1. Find the positive integer $x$ for which $\frac{x^2}{740-x}$ is a prime number.

Edit: I've decided to post the questions separately as advised. Let me start with this one.

I just used the choices! I had no idea on how to proceed but the most I could do was figure that the answer had to share  factors with 740.

Comment: What contest was it?

Comment: Please, one question per post.  Voting to close as needs more focus.  Did you make any progress on any of them?  For 3, presumably the expression was supposed to be equal to something.  You can't satisfy an expression.

Comment: Agreed - please post each one as a separate question, detailing what attempts you took to solve each one, or why you found it to be a difficult/impossible question

Comment: Noted, thanks. And the contest was the introductory part for selecting students for the IMO and the Pan African Math Olympiad

Comment: Please go and give all the parts more descriptive titles, currently they don't tell anyone anything about the question contained within, which means people are less likely to click on them

Answer (score 2):

We are going to use 2 facts:

1. $\frac{x^{2}}{740-x}=p$ implies $p|x$ since $p$ is a prime
2. Because of (1), $x^{2}=740p-px$ implies $p^{2}|740p$ i.e. $p|740$

Since $p$ is a prime which divides $740$, it must be either $2,5,$ or $37$. A quick check reveal that only $p=37$ has integer $x$ solution which is $148.$

Comment: Thank you so much